# A xml editor for messed files on linux

Tags: xml, linux, editor, indentation, reportico

Hello I have a tool called reportico that generates xml conf file automatically.
But that xml file are messed up, I mean there are no indentation and almost all is in the same line.
That file is quite long.
I'm looking for a editor that ordinates that xml file in order I can edit it easily.
I use linux so that editor has to run on linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

```
xmllint --format my_file_name.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit for Linux (UEX)](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/uex.html) has in menu **Format** a command to convert single-line XML feed to properly formatted XML document.

See the [feature list of UEX](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/uex/features.html) for other XML related features like integrated xmllint support and an XML manager.